# Parallels desktop virtual machines cannot communicate when Mac has no network connection

Tags: network, wifi, virtualization, parallels-desktop

I have two virtual machines running on Parallels desktop (v11 if that makes a difference).  They are operating in Shared network mode.

When I have a wireless or Bluetooth network connection they can communicate between each other fine.

When I lose that connection (phone tether drops out, flying, etc) the virtual machines no longer are able to communicate with each other.

I have also tried the network in Host Only mode to no avail.

Is there some way I can have these virtual machines communicate with each other even when I do not have an external network connection?

Comment: Do you mean it cannot communicate outside its virtual subnet or it cannot communicate with *each other* on the same virtual subnet?

Comment: It can no longer communicate with each other

Comment: Clearly, they're not actually operating over your local network—it's traveling from you, out over the wider internet, then back to you your local machine. Why, I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Parallels Knowledge Base](http://kb.parallels.com/8978) the following indicates an internet connection is required for this to work.  No idea why that would be a requirement.

```
Network problems in the virtual machine
Article ID: 8978
Created On: Sep 14, 2010
Last Review: Nov 24, 2015
Views:
APPLIES TO:

    Parallels Desktop for Mac
    Parallels Desktop for Mac Pro Edition
    Parallels Desktop for Mac Business Edition
    Parallels Access

Note: Your Mac must be connected to the Internet for virtual machines to be able to connect.
```